# Error when compiling Z3 unstable branch

Tags: c++, gcc, z3

I am trying to build z3 unstable branch on OSX and I followed the instructions in the readme file (python scripts/mk_make.py then cd build then make) but I got the following error.

```
Testing ar...
Testing g++...
Testing gcc...
Testing OpenMP...
Host platform:  Darwin 13.0.0
C++ Compiler:   g++
C Compiler  :   gcc
Arithmetic:     internal
OpenMP:         False
Prefix:         /Library
64-bit:         True
Python version: 2.7

...
src/shell/datalog_frontend.cpp
make: CXX@: No such file or directory
make: *** [shell/datalog_frontend.o] Error 1
```

I am new to OSX so I am not sure what went wrong. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You should probably use `clang` as your compiler on `OS X`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried using CXX=clang++ CC=clang python scripts/mk_make.py  but still got the same error as before.

Comment: Are you sure you have all of the code and the dependencies?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did not change any thing in the code. I was trying to compile it.